# License question on router cisco

Tags: router, cisco-ios, license

Could anyone help me on license question on router cisco.
Is **ADV IP SERVICES LIC** the license on router Cisco that all I need if I want to run these features on my router Cisco : **L3VPN, L2VPN, VPLS and QoS** ?

Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: Depending on the router model, advanced IP services should normally give access to all features on a Cisco router.

Comment: What is the router model?

Comment: the router model is ASR1001-X. It's now Ok, thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advanced IP Services provides all the features you are looking for.  You can go to Cisco's website: Cisco Feature Navigator, and use it to compare two software releases, or just one, and see exactly what features it has.  Here's the link: https://cfn.cloudapps.cisco.com/ITDIT/CFN/jsp/index.jsp

BlackWolf